# Create subpages in default Wordpress menu

Tags: menus, multisite

I've got this code below working to create a default menu. I was wondering how I would create sub-items/subpages...

```
// Check if the menu exists
$menu_exists = wp_get_nav_menu_object('Main Menu');

// If it doesn't exist, let's create it.
if( !$menu_exists){
    $menu_id = wp_create_nav_menu('Main Menu');


  // Set up default menu items

    wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, 0, array(
        'menu-item-title' =>  __('Home'),
        'menu-item-type' => 'post_type',
        'menu-item-object' => 'page',
        'menu-item-url' => get_permalink($pageId),
        'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));
}
```

[edit] Sorry all! I forgot to mention that I was implementing this menu on every installation of a Wordpress multisite. So when you do a new installation this default menu would already be in place.

Comment: What happens when you use the Custom Nav Menu feature as it's intended, instead of trying to force a square peg into a round hole?

Comment: @ChipBennett Sorry, I was hoping to this on a Wordpress Multisite installation.

Comment: What does the use of Multisite have to do with `wp_nav_menu()`?

Comment: Whenever you do a new installation of a multisite, the theme comes with a pre-existing menu

Answer (score 0):

I was also doing the same thing check out this question Hope this will help you .

[Menu page Exists or not](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119281/check-if-add-menu-page-exists-or-not)

Answer (score -1):

Are you using one of the default themes or something similar? You normally organise sub-pages by setting the 'Parent' attribute in the 'Edit Page' page. You'll probably find that the default menu will then show these correctly.

Alternatively, you can always edit the structure and order of a menu through the WP dashboard...Appearance...Menus. You drag and drop pages or categories into the menu as required. If you drag a page to the right inside the structure box, it will make it a sub-item in the menu.

Comment: Sorry, I was hoping to this on a Wordpress Multisite installation.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't properly look at what you were doing!