# How do I check menu slug in WordPress?

Tags: menus

I’m developing a new wordpress plugin, I’d like to check if my admin menu slug “xyz” is used bu another plugin in the site.

Is there any method to check the current used slugs?

**Please note that I'm looking for slugs in admin menus NOT posts slugs**

Comment: I Found the solution [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119281/check-if-add-menu-page-exists-or-not) This is exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

There is no **official** way as far as I know.  You should be prefixing your menu_slug's with some string that is *almost* guaranteed to be unique (e.g., 'your_company_name_your_plugin_name_your_menu_slug').

That said, looking into the source for [add_submenu_page()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L1137), the following should work, but I offer no guarantees (and, see the **BIG** caveat below):

```
/**
 * test whether $menu_slug is already used in $parent_slug in admin menus
 *
 * This function should be called **no sooner** than the 'admin_menu' action!
 *
 * Note: this has only been tested in WP 4.7 and relies on undocumented internals,
 * and MIGHT not work in ANY other version of WP!!
 *
 * @param $menu_slug string the proposed menu slug
 * @param $parent_slug string the parent slug
 * @return bool true if $menu_slug already exists in $parent_menu, false otherwise
 */
function
is_menu_slug_available ($menu_slug, $parent_slug)
{
    global $_registered_pages ;

    $menu_slug = plugin_basename ($menu_slug) ;
    $parent_slug = plugin_basename ($parent_slug) ;

    $hookname = get_plugin_page_hookname ($menu_slug, $parent_slug) ;

    return (!(isset ($_registered_pages[$hookname]) && true === $_registered_pages[$hookname])) ;
}
```

## Caveat

It is almost always a **BAD IDEA** to rely on undocumented internals such as this!  Since they are undocumented, the WP team could change how things work under the hood **at ANY time** and you'd be screwed!

Comment: if this is _really_ important to you, then you should propose an enhancement to WP thru [Trac](https://make.wordpress.org/core/reports/)

Comment: I understand the (caveat) and appreciate your efforts, but it seems that the global variable `$_registered_pages` is null

Comment: `$_registered_pages` will likely be null if you call the func before the `admin_menu` action has been fired.  But since you shouldn't be calling `add_submenu_page()` before then, anyway, you should be fine.  BTW, are you using WP 4.7?  As the comment in the code says, I've only tested it in 4.7, if you're using _any_ other version your "mileage may very".